# Summing an order total in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, variables

I have a function calling a function for taking user info, then totaling the order. I have been able to get it to print the item total, but having trouble printing the order total once the user is done. If I'm using a function to calculate the math, then a function to get the user input, and now a third function that loops the order process, would I be better off modifying the math function, or the loop function to obtain the order total?

I have tried adding a sums = 0 variable at first, then modifying the variable that calls the function with sums += userVariable but I think that is my problem since the variable calls a function, not an integer. 
My building functions are:

```py
#currency function
def format_currency(x):
    currency = '${:,.2f}'.format(x)
    return (currency)

#math function
def calc_pizza_charge(s,m,o,q):
    smPizza = 6.50
    mdPizza = 9.50
    lgPizza = 11.50
    meatPrice = 3.50
    vegPrice = 1.50
    charge = 0
    if s == 1:
        charge = smPizza
    elif s == 2:
        charge = mdPizza
    else:
        charge = lgPizza
    if m > 1:
        charge += (m-1)*meatPrice
    if o > 1:
        charge += (o-1)*vegPrice
    charge = q*charge
    return charge

#user input function
def get_pizza_info():
    size = int(input("Enter pizza size (1 small, 2 medium, 3 large): "))
    numMeat = int(input("Enter number meat toppings: "))
    nonMeat = int(input("Enter number or non-meat toppings: "))
    count = int(input("Enter number of pizzas ordered: "))
    return calc_pizza_charge(size, numMeat, nonMeat, count)
```

```py
#looping order process
def take_customer_order():
    done = False
    sums = 0
    while not done:
        inval = input("Order a pizza? (Y/N): ").capitalize()
        if inval == "Y":
            nextPizza = get_pizza_info()
            print("Pizza Total: " + format_currency(nextPizza))
        elif inval == "N":
            done = True
            sums += nextPizza
        print("Order Total: " +format_currency(nextPizza))
```

Expected:

```
 Enter pizza size (1 small, 2 medium, 3 large): 3
 Enter number meat toppings: 2
 Enter number or non-meat toppings: 3
 Enter number of pizzas ordered: 2
 Pizza Total: $36.00
 Order a pizza? (Y/N): Y
 Enter pizza size (1 small, 2 medium, 3 large): 1
 Enter number meat toppings: 1
 Enter number or non-meat toppings: 2
 Enter number of pizzas ordered: 1
 Pizza Total: $8.00
 Order a pizza? (Y/N): N
 Order Total: $44.00
```

Actual:

```
Order a pizza? (Y/N): y
Enter pizza size (1 small, 2 medium, 3 large): 3
Enter number meat toppings: 2
Enter number or non-meat toppings: 2
Enter number of pizzas ordered: 2
Pizza Total: $33.00
Order Total: $33.00
Order a pizza? (Y/N): y
Enter pizza size (1 small, 2 medium, 3 large): 2
Enter number meat toppings: 1
Enter number or non-meat toppings: 2
Enter number of pizzas ordered: 2
Pizza Total: $22.00
Order Total: $22.00
Order a pizza? (Y/N): n
Order Total: $22.00
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/guita/Documents/School/CSCI100/CSCI100_Lab5_P/CSCI100_Lab5_P/problem4.py", line 6, in <module>
    print("Order Total: " + lab5_functions.format_currency(total))
  File "C:\Users\guita\Documents\School\CSCI100\CSCI100_Lab5_P\CSCI100_Lab5_P\lab5_functions.py", line 7, in format_currency
    currency = '${:,.2f}'.format(x)
TypeError: unsupported format string passed to NoneType.__format__
```

Answer (score 0):

To make a minimal example just replace all your pizza logic with a function that returns `1.0`.  You would then be able to easily see your 2 issues:

- The `sums +=` is inside the "N" instead of the "Y" branch
- You print out the nextPizza value instead of the sums value for the order total